# Node on IIS for server-rendering Angular 4+ application

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have my angular 4+ web application hosted on IIS as our backend is in C#.NET and we use entity framework.As Angular is SPA framework SEO has taken a hit.I tried server-side rendering using Angular universal.It works fine with Nodejs server as done in their demo example but now I want to know how can I use Nodejs as  in Angular 4+ web app hosted on IIS.

I have checked this :https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode  .It is not in developement anymore. I locally hosted my app on IIS and installed iisnode as per docs but it gives me error like this:

It gives an error like this : **HRESULT: 0x2**

How can i solve this issue?.Also,I want to know is there any other way to handle this issue.

Comment: experiencing the same problem

Comment: @DanielNetzer Meanwhile you can checkout errors of node server in logfiles of IIS.

Comment: I've found the errors, but the node server doesnt manage to write the log files, can you share you web.config and server.ts?

Comment: @DanielNetzer  IIS node creates a folder named "iisode" in the hosted folder in which log files are generated.Also, check out this link: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/359

Comment: I just added full permissions to iisusr1 and created the logs folder manually and now it works.